# how to show data weekly in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i have transport data say example :-

```
select * from  DR_TRANSPORT

PRODUCTS  TR_DATE      SHIPMENT
----------------------------
IRON     19/02/2021   Y
COTTON   26/02/2021   Y
RICE     20/02/2021   N
FRUITS   01/03/2021   Y
STEEL    07/03/2021   Y
```

now user will pass to date and from date say :19/02/2021 and 26/03/2021

expected data :

`````
Weeks Goods
------------
week1 fruits
week2 IRON
WEEK3 COTTON
````
based on the user dates we need to extract weeks and get the o/p as above
`````

Comment: How are you defining a week? Starting on a Sunday, or Monday, or some other fixed day; or with the 'from date' as the start of the first week, whatever actual day that falls on? What do you want to see if there are multiple goods within one of those weeks?

Comment: for example user has given like today date as Tuesday so i need to pull from Tuesday to Sunday one week and from Monday to Sunday another week .

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the start of the ISO-weeks:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(
         (TRUNC(tr_date, 'IW') - TRUNC(DATE '2021-02-19', 'IW'))/7
       ) + 1 AS week,
       products
FROM   table_name
WHERE  tr_date BETWEEN DATE '2021-02-19' AND DATE '2021-03-26'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (PRODUCTS, TR_DATE, SHIPMENT) AS
SELECT 'IRON',   DATE '2021-02-19', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'COTTON', DATE '2021-02-26', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RICE',   DATE '2021-02-20', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRUITS', DATE '2021-03-01', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'STEEL',  DATE '2021-03-07', 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | WEEK | PRODUCTS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | IRON |
> | 2 | COTTON |
> | 1 | RICE |
> | 3 | FRUITS |
> | 3 | STEEL |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b593978d8640810843d278766c4af185)*